# como podria insertar esto

Tags: php, jquery

tengo este script :

```
$(document).on('click', '.tipo-sangre', function(event){

  var tipo = $(this).data("sangre");
  $(tipo).appendTo("#tipo_sangre");

});
```

lo q  quiero es q al darle clik me pase el valor del var a un input tipo hidden para poder hacer el request y guardarlo en la base de datos pero no se como enviarlo al input por cierto el inpout es el **`id= #tipo_sangre`** como podría hacer para que el var se guarde en el y poder enviarlo con request

Comment: Intenta con `$("#tipo_sangre").val(tipo);`

Comment: no me funciona . lo que necesito es que el valor que recoge la var sea como un string que el usuario escribió para poder insertarlo en la base de datos por eso es script debe pasarlo con un click cuando se elija un input que lleva ese data-sangre

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Entiendo que lo que quieres hacer es recoger el valor de la variable "tipo" y ponerlo en el campo hidden, no?

```
$(document).on('click', '.tipo-sangre', function(event){

  var tipo = $(this).data("sangre");
  //esta última parte la hacías al reves.
  //primero asignas a que elemento de html haces referencia (con el selector de id, en tu caso, y luego con el metodo "val" le asignas el valor que quieres (la variable tipo, en tu caso)
  $("#tipo_sangre").val(tipo);

});
```

Comment: eso era muchas gracias x la ayuda :)